# How to create/provide multiple example apps for a flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Flutter seems to have a very strict/rigid structure for plugins with `example` folder and all contents inside that folder.

I want to provide multiple examples with my plugin. Something like `examples` folder and then `examples/demo1` and `examples/demo2` as two different app examples.

I tried doing this but `flutter run` or `pub get` command breaks with this change. it's gets stuck with below error which wasn't thrown with exact same code in previous structure before change. Also my app actually follow embedding v2 code so this error is completely false too.

```
The plugin `<MY PLUGIN>` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on
https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.
```

Somehow is it expecting that there should be only one example and that too with `example` folder only ?

Can someone help, and if possible point me to a plugin project where it's using multiple examples ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying multiple ways to deal with the situation,

I ended up with a good enough solution.

I moved entire flutter repo inside an `sdk` directory, and then Introduced a `samples` folder at `root` level which can contain multiple sample applications.

`sdk` itself has a default sample app under `example` folder which I kept so sdk can ship with one example project.

Final structure look like below,

```
- Root
  - sdk
    - Flutter plugin project (like android/example/ios/lib directory etc.)
  - samples
    - sampleOne
    - sampleTwo
```

I then mentioned relative path to sdk for `sampleOne` or `sampleTwo` inside their `pubspec.yaml` like `path: ../../sdk/`

When I want to open `sampleOne` in `AndroidStudio`, I import `sampleOne` directory and it works like charm. Make sure you don't import entire `samples` directory or `sampleOne/Android`.

For any regular Flutter commands for plugin, I run them inside `sdk` directory and everything works fine as expected. So I would run `publish` or `pub get` inside `root/sdk` directory